# OS X Lion Recovery hangs on "Downloading additional components"

Tags: macos, recovery

Booted into the recovery partition and attempted to reinstall. First pass, nothing happened. Second pass, same. Backed up and erased the install partition, tried a third time. Seemed to be fine until ~90% and now it's stuck at "About 2 hours and 25 minutes remaining". Can still access menus, the bar is animated, display dims after X minutes like it should, but it's clearly not downloading anything.

The closest thing I've found to a fix is mention on the Apple forums where multiple users mentioned RAM being the problem. How in the hell can increased RAM break an OS install?

And if it's not that, then what? What else can break a clean install?